# Expected unqualified-id before '&' token (Mininet VM, try/catch on std::invalid_argument)

Tags: c++, mininet

I am getting the following error when compiling on the Mininet virtual machine using g++.

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '&' token
} catch (const std::invalid_argument& ia) {
                                    ^
```

Code:

```
try {
  port = std::stoi(argv[3]);
  if (port < 1024 || port > 65535) {
    cerr << "Error: port number must be in the range 1024 to 65535";
    exit(1);
  }
} catch (const std::invalid_argument& ia) {
  cerr << "Error: missing or additional arguments: Expected number for port" << endl;
}
```

I do not get the error when compiling on macOS with the same settings. Removing const or the & simply results in another error; doing `std::invalid_argument ia` results in "error: expected type-specifier"

Since I can't replicate this on my mac and this only occurs on the Mininet VM, I am at a loss as to the cause and potential fixes.

Note: To clarify, I ran `sudo apt-get install g++` on the virtual machine today, and I am compiling with C++11 using the following: `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O -o code_name code_name.cpp

Comment: Did you have `#include <stdexcept>`?

Comment: Did you `#include <stdexcept>`? It may work without in certain cases (due to indirect include in certain `std` implementations). I found this in [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument).

Comment: @Justin Whoa, that actually fixed it. Thank you - it must have been an include that isn't done by default on the VM's OS.

Comment: @AndrewFan `#include`s are not done by default

Comment: It's an issue with the environment then, since on macOS, cstring and I guess stdexcept as well are automatically included.

Comment: For posting SO questions on errors like this, I strongly recommend you post the entire file, including the `int main() { ... }` and all the `#include`s. Also, if you are saying what compiler you are using, it's helpful to include the version (`g++ --version`). At that point, you may even be able to paste the code into [the compiler explorer at godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/), choose the right compiler, and share a link so that it's extremely easy for others to reproduce your errors. See [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

On Mininet's VM, `#include <stdexcept>` is required in order to use the functionality detailed in the question. This include file (among others) is not necessary on macOS, where it is included by default.

`#include <stdexcept>` fixes this specific problem.

Comment: Do note that it's perfectly acceptable for the standard library you were using on the Mac to change this at any time. It has certainly happened within Microsoft's standard library before.

Comment: It's always necessary in the sense that a compiler is not required to accept your program if you don't do it.